# Ignore properties of class when using WCF ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json

Tags: c#, wcf, json

I'm using WCF for JSON services using this format:

```
[OperationContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(ComplexResult))]
[WebInvoke(
            Method = "GET",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
MyClass MyFunction(string myParams);
```

This works great, however it has a limitation. I can't ignore properties of my class that I'm serializing to JSON. If I use the JavaScriptSerializer class then I can put [ScriptIgnore] attributes on the properties I want to ignore and they won't be serialized in the JSON, however this does not work with the method above.

Is there a way to exclude properties of the classes getting serialized to JSON using the ResponseFormat Json method?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

WCF by default uses the `DataContractJsonSerializer` to serialize objects. Depending on how `MyClass` is defined, you can use different attributes to prevent members from being serialized:

- If MyClass doesn't have any attribute (i.e., it's a "POCO" type), you can use the `[IgnoreDataMember]` attribute in the members you don't want serialized
- If MyClass is decorated with `[Serializable]`, you can use the `[NotSerialized]` attribute in those members
- If MyClass is decorated with `[DataContract]`, then you just need to *not add* `[DataMember]` to the members you don't want serialized.